# Trying to change a Label from two enteries when Button pressed and display on another page? | Xamarin | C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a Xamarin App, where I can enter text in two entries and then after clicking the button, I want to display combination of the two entries on next page.
How to display labels in a list?

Comment: This is not a question.  It is a list of requirements.  Please read [ask] for help on how to write a great SO question.

Comment: @Navreet -  _where I can enter text in two labels_. How can you enter text in `Labels`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean ***enter text in two labels*** is ***the enter text in two entrys*** . Here is a sample for reference :

**PageA** - Xaml :

```
<Entry x:Name="entryone"/>
<Entry x:Name="entrytwo"/>
<Button Text="Push" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

ContentPage - `Button_Clicked` :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      SecondPage secondPage = new SecondPage();
      secondPage.previousPageValue = entryone.Text + entrytwo.Text; //Set value to next page
      Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
 }
```

**PageB** - Xaml :

```
<Label x:Name="label"/>
```

ContentPage - show value when page `OnAppearing` ;

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    public string previousPageValue; //Declare here

    public SecondPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        label.Text = previousPageValue;
    }
}
```

[image: First Page] [image: Second Page]

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, can you tell me where should I declare the previousPageValue ?

Comment: @navreetsidhu If be helpful ,you can mark it .And if other problems , also can update questuion.

Comment: Yes the answer is helpful but can you tell me that you used previoudPageValue variable where did you declare it in SecondPage?

Comment: @navreetsidhu Okey , it declared in `SecondPage.Xaml.cs` . I have updated answer .